# Automatic creation of mutiple file object in python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, logging

am receiving packets from the serial line from multiple modems the ID of the modem is attached to each packet end.  for each modem I want to create a log file named with modemID,  (number of modems is not determined) .if the log file is already opened I want to write into it

```
if logEnabled :
          filename =res[-3:] # last three bytes of the packets are the modemID   
          if not filename  in OpenedLogFile :  
                OpenedLogFile += filename   

                f= open(os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, filename), 'w',0)
                f.write(res + '\n')

          else:
               f.write(res + '\n')
```

Comment: And ? What did you get ? Errors ? Please described what and where is your problem.

Comment: the problem is: let us say the first modem ID is 14 . modem 14 sent a Pkt, the code above will open a file named 14 and then write the received packet into it .then modemID 15 send a Pkt same process will happen. now in OpenLogFile we have 14, 15 if modem 14 send another packet the code will execute f.write and here is the problem, because the code will write to the last opened file. How to make the code write to the right file when it receive the file name(modemID)

Comment: What kind of object is `OpenedLogFile` ? A dictionary ?

Comment: just to store the names of opened logs 14,15,16 which equals the modem IDs

Comment: Could you provide a bit more of your source code just to check how to define the best answer ?

Comment: can I send it to you by Email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to keep all log files opened and switch from one to another, is to extend the use of your dictionary `OpenedLogFile` by adding parameters to the key.

**Step1** - Be sure to declare your dictionary.

```
OpenedLogFile = dict()
```

**Step2** - Update your dictionary when modemID log file not open.

```
filename =res[-3:]
if not filename  in OpenedLogFile :
    OpenedLogFile[filename] = [ filename ] # record the key as first parameter
    f= open(os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, filename), 'w')
    OpenedLogFile[filename].append(f) # add file pointer as second parameter
    f.write(res + '\n')
```

**Step3** - Otherwise reuse the modemID log from your dictionary

```
else:
    f= OpenedLogFile[filename][1] # recover file pointer from filename key
    f.write(res + '\n')
```

**Step4** - Then at the end, it is also easy to close all modemID log

```
for fp in OpenedLogFile:
    f = OpenedLogFile[fp][1] # recover each file pointer
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Man! everything is ok now

Comment: @Mikle-86, if the answer is 'ok', please, vote for or accept it.